# How do I close and delete a file on a synced OneDrive using VBA or R?

Tags: r, excel, vba, sharepoint, onedrive

I have an Excel file with a macro in it that is supposed to do the following:

1. Copy a sheet named "SavingsExport" to a new file
2. Save the new file to OneDrive
3. Close the new file
4. Run an R code (that takes the newly created file and puts it into a database)
5. Delete the newly created file

The code runs fine but ultimately doesn't delete the file. After Step 3 I can see that the file is physically closed, but for some reason OneDrive still thinks it's open and therefore won't delete it.

If I go into OneDrive Online and manually delete it, it warns me *"It looks like someone has this file open. Are you sure you want to delete?"*. I say yes and it deletes it, but otherwise I can't delete the file either through R or VBA because for some reason it doesn't seem to close properly.

I've tried several iterations of code, nothing seems to work. Here are some of the variations I've tried:

```
        'Copy Savings Export (Step 1 from Above)
        Sheets("SavingsExport").Select
        Sheets("SavingsExport").Copy
               
        'Save file to OneDrive (Step 2 from Above)
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & fName1, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
        Set DestinWB = Workbooks.Open("https://ORG.sharepoint.com/teams/EPSDataAnalytics/Shared Documents/DART App/Temp Files/SavingsExport.xlsx")
    
        'Close the temporary file (Step 3 from Above)
        DestinWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
              
        'Run R Code (Step 4 from Above)
        Irrelevant here... Removed for brevity

        'Delete Temp File (Step 5 from Above)
        Kill ("https://ORG.sharepoint.com/teams/EPSDataAnalytics/Shared Documents/DART App/Temp Files/SavingsExport.xlsx")
```

Alternatively, I've tried using my mapped drive instead of the OneDrive address:

```
        'Copy Savings Export (Step 1 from Above)
        Sheets("SavingsExport").Select
        Sheets("SavingsExport").Copy
        
        'Save file to OneDrive (Step 2 from Above)
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & fName1, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
        Set DestinWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\UserData\" & UserName() & "\Siemens AG\EPS Data Analytics - Documents\DART App\Temp Files\SavingsExport.xlsx")
    
        'Close the temporary file (Step 3 from Above)
        DestinWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
              
        'Run R Code (Step 4 from Above)
        Irrelevant here... Removed for brevity

        'Delete Temp File (Step 5 from Above)
        Kill ("C:\UserData\" & UserName() & "\Siemens AG\EPS Data Analytics - Documents\DART App\Temp Files\SavingsExport.xlsx")
```

I also tried both of these options with a different method for saving and closing the temp file (Steps 2 and 3), also with and without the delay commands:

```
        'Copy Savings Export (Step 1 from Above)
        Sheets("SavingsExport").Select
        Sheets("SavingsExport").Copy
        
        'Save and close Temp file (Steps 2 & 3 from Above)
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
        ActiveWorkbook.Close _
        SaveChanges:=True, _
        Filename:="https://ORG.sharepoint.com/teams/EPSDataAnalytics/Shared Documents/DART App/Temp Files/SavingsExport.xlsx"
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
        
        'Run R Code (Step 4 from Above)
        Irrelevant here... Removed for brevity

        'Delete Temp File (Step 5 from Above)
        Kill ("https://ORG.sharepoint.com/teams/EPSDataAnalytics/Shared Documents/DART App/Temp Files/SavingsExport.xlsx")
```

Beyond this, I also tried deleting the file as part of the R code with all of the different options below, all of which return [1] FALSE with a warning message saying "Invalid argument":

```
file.remove(paste("\\\\ORG.sharepoint.com\\teams\\EPSDataAnalytics\\Shared%20Documents\\DART%20App\\Temp%20Files\\SavingsExport.xlsx", sep = ""))

file.remove(paste("https:\\\\ORG.sharepoint.com\\teams\\EPSDataAnalytics\\Shared%20Documents\\DART%20App\\Temp%20Files\\SavingsExport.xlsx", sep = ""))

file.remove(paste("\\\\ORG.sharepoint.com\\teams\\EPSDataAnalytics\\Shared Documents\\DART App\\Temp Files\\SavingsExport.xlsx", sep = ""))

file.remove(paste("https:\\\\ORG.sharepoint.com\\teams\\EPSDataAnalytics\\Shared Documents\\DART App\\Temp Files\\SavingsExport.xlsx", sep = ""))

file.remove(paste("//ORG.sharepoint.com/teams/EPSDataAnalytics/Shared%20Documents/DART%20App/Temp%20Files/SavingsExport.xlsx", sep = ""))

file.remove(paste("https://ORG.sharepoint.com/teams/EPSDataAnalytics/Shared%20Documents/DART%20App/Temp%20Files/SavingsExport.xlsx", sep = ""))

file.remove(paste("//ORG.sharepoint.com/teams/EPSDataAnalytics/Shared Documents/DART App/Temp Files/SavingsExport.xlsx", sep = ""))

file.remove(paste("https://ORG.sharepoint.com/teams/EPSDataAnalytics/Shared Documents/DART App/Temp Files/SavingsExport.xlsx", sep = ""))
```

Any ideas?!?

Comment: Maybe you can consider the R package Microsoft365R (see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Microsoft365R/index.html). This packages allows the user to connect to a "OneDrive"

Comment: I looked through all the vignettes, and there aren't any commands for deleting files, only opening and sharing. Thanks for the starting point though.

Comment: I will check this in detail. I will try it on my personal OneDrive. I think it is possible by using some functions of the R6 class.

Answer (score 0):

I use to following code to connect to my personal oneDrive :

```
library(Microsoft365R)
oneDrive_Obj <- get_personal_onedrive()
```

and I obtained :

```
Using authorization_code flow
Creating Microsoft Graph login for tenant 'consumers'
Using authorization_code flow
Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
Authentication complete.
<Personal OneDrive of Emmanuel Hamel>
  directory id: XXX 
---
  Methods:
    create_folder, create_share_link, delete, delete_item, do_operation, download_file, get_item, get_item_properties, get_list_pager, list_files, list_items, list_shared_files,
    list_shared_items, open_item, set_item_properties, sync_fields, update, upload_file
```

I can use

```
oneDrive_Obj$delete_item("test")
```

to delete the folder "test" on my oneDrive.

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel. Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. My site is a Business OneDrive. I tried get_business_onedrive(), which didn't work. I got closer with get_sharepoint_site(), but it looks like my SharePoint site isn't set up to allow API access. So all in all, this isn't a viable solution for me for this particular instance. Thanks for the effort though!

Answer (score 0):

Check bellow thread I started based on a very similar issue.

I've maybe found a workaround which might help you, too.

(Saving the online / synchronized file with `saveas` method to local temp folder prior to close and release the var).

[Unable to delete OneDrive/Sharepoint file, encountering XML error 207 (error 423 - file locked)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76371720/unable-to-delete-onedrive-sharepoint-file-encountering-xml-error-207-error-423)

It looks like the `workbooks.close` do not properly close the workbook and so, deletion is not allowed.
Simply opening / closing the file with Excel desktop app will then release the file for deletion.

Comment: Can you suggest an edit to an existing post? This is not really an Answer in the S.O. sense.

Comment: Ryan, I deleted my comment here and changed the answer because, I do believe, it could be an answer / solution to original post. :) Thanks.