# Unable to delete OneDrive/Sharepoint file, encountering XML error 207 (error 423 - file locked)

Tags: excel, vba

I really can't figure out my issue. :)

I'm coding a tool to process an export (xlsx) file from SAP.
The sole thing I do with this file is to open it (**readonly = true**), copy a sheet to my tool then I close the source file (**savechanges = false**).

Data processing is then handled in the tool.
So before processing data, once source wokbook is closed, I delete it (according setting in the tool).
This is working fine locally (with kill) but it's randomly failing if the source file is on OneDrive / Sharepoint (XML error 207, ResponseText is error 423, file is locked).

I tried to copy source file to the synchronised folder then I delete the file (https, not locally) **without** opening it = it looks to work everytime.
If I open / copy / close as mentioned above = random error 207 (423 - File is locked).

```
Response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><D:multistatus  xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns:Office="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:Repl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/repl/" xmlns:Z="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:"><D:response><D:href>https://MyCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/pwa2/Customer/E/E12%20Supply%20Chain/PROCUREMENT/0_ZPSR313/export.xlsx</D:href><D:status>HTTP/1.1 423 Locked</D:status></D:response></D:multistatus>
```

Once in this situation, most of the time I can't even delete the file from Sharepoint folder, I have a message stating it's used by another user (I'm sole one accessing the folder during my trials).
I have to open the file with Desktop Excel app, <s>save it</s> and then the file is not locked anymore !

Edit: actually, I just need to open the file and close to release it, not necessary to save it.

Edit: here is the exact error message from Sharepoint:

> The server has encountered the following error(s):
> export.XLSX
> The file is currently checked out or locked for editing by another user.

Do you have any clue how I can avoid this behaviour ? :)
Thanks a lot.

Here's the code, if I comment this, I can properly delete the online file.

```
    Set source_workbook = Workbooks.Open(SelectedFile, ReadOnly = True)
    FlPath = source_workbook.Path

'    source_workbook.Windows(1).Visible = False

    source_workbook.Sheets(1).Copy before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    WaitForm.StepLbl.Caption = "Waiting for raw ZPSR313 to close"
    DoEvents

    source_workbook.Close (False)
```

I tried opening the file with readonly = false, tried to saveas the file in local temp folder expecting online file to be released.
I tried application.wait before deleteting the file.
Killing the local file work but the online file remains.

Edit: there's neither links nor macros on the source file.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: unfortunately, does not work... so painful to manage files on synchronized folder...

I'll confirm this later after additional testing but it looks like I found a workaround.

Between `workbooks.open` and `workbooks.close` I added a `workbook.saveas` to `Environ("TEMP")` (user's local temporary folder).

Saving the file seems to release the online one avoiding error 423 - File is locked.

I also set the workbook's var to `Nothing`.
Here's the updated code:

```
Set source_workbook = Workbooks.Open(SelectedFile, ReadOnly = True)
FlPath = source_workbook.Path

source_workbook.Windows(1).Visible = False

source_workbook.Sheets(1).Copy before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
WaitForm.StepLbl.Caption = "Waiting for raw ZPSR313 to close"
DoEvents


If FlPathUNC <> FlPath Then 'If OD / SP file: save as the file on Temp folder to avoid having error 207 / 423 file is locked
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'allow to overwrite without prompt
    source_workbook.SaveAs Filename:=Environ("TEMP") & "\" & "TempExport.XLSX", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False, _
                    AccessMode:=xlExclusive, ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If

source_workbook.Close (False)
Set source_workbook = Nothing
```